# Multiple Logistic Regression using Scikit in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

How can I find a summary of the errors, confidence intervals, etc. using scikit-learn linearmodel.LogisticRegression?
I can see the coefficients using result.coef_  (say result = linearmodel.LogisticRegression(params).fit(X,y)), but I cannot see how precise they are.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK sklearn does not provide this. You have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I confirm it does not exist in scikit-learn.